# Awk & bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, shell, awk

When I paste this command into the terminal (ubuntu 18.04):

```
cat file.txt | awk -F, BEGIN { OFS = FS } {if ($2 == "") $2 = last2; else last2 = $2 print}
```

I get:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Sorry can you post what you mean. I tried combinations of quotes and it's not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `awk` command as you have it in the question, each single word and character will be parsed by the shell and passed to the `awk` commands not as a single script but at separate commands. And some of the combinations of characters are special in the shell, like the parenthesis or the environment-variable expansions like `$2`.

Of course that's not what you seem to want, instead you should pass all the code to `awk` as a single *unexpanded* string (you don't want the shell to attempt to expand `$2`), and for that you need to surround the code with single-quotes, as in

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } {if ($2 == "") $2 = last2; else last2 = $2 print}'
```